# FragmentStatePagerAdapter Fullscreen Bitmap out of memory Android

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm working on a Galaxy S and I followed [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)
 to display a set of images from a GridView in a separate Fullscreen Activity. 
I implemented the FragmentStatePagerAdapter and an AsyncTask but I still incur in OutOfMemory error and I don't know anymore where to crash my head! 
I also implemented calculateInSampleSize as google said (it returns values like 1-2), but if I set option.inSampleSize = 16 (for testing) everything goes right!!
There are 8 images loaded from resource id and the largest is approximately 2560*1600.

I know it is a very asked question but I didn't find any solutions either in google doc nor in this site.

Thanks.

Here my FullscreenActivity

```
public class FullScreenActivity extends FragmentActivity{

private ImagePagerAdapter adapter;
private ViewPager viewPager;
int imageWidth;
int imageHeight;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

    imageWidth =  Utils.getScreenWidth(this);
    imageHeight =  Utils.getScreenHeight(this);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.Viewpager);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    int position = i.getIntExtra("position", 0);

    adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), ItemList.LISTA_GALLERY_ID.length);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // displaying selected image first
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
}

public void loadBitmap(int resId, ImageView mImageView) {
    BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(mImageView);
    task.execute(resId);        
}

class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
    private int data = 0;

    public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
        // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    // Decode image in background.
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        data = params[0];
        return Utils.decodeBitmapFromResource(getResources(), data,
                imageWidth, imageHeight);
    }

    // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
            final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

And here my adapters

```
public class FullScreenImageAdapter {
public static class ImagePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private final int mSize;

    public ImagePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int size) {
        super(fm);
        mSize = size;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mSize;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ImageDetailFragment.newInstance(position);
    }
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object){
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }



}

public static class ImageDetailFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String IMAGE_DATA_EXTRA = "resId";
    private int mImageNum;
    private ImageView mImageView;

    static ImageDetailFragment newInstance(int imageNum) {
        final ImageDetailFragment f = new ImageDetailFragment();
        final Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(IMAGE_DATA_EXTRA, imageNum);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }   

    //  Empty constructor, required as per Fragment docs
    public ImageDetailFragment() {}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mImageNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt(IMAGE_DATA_EXTRA) : -1;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // image_detail_fragment.xml contains just an ImageView
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fullscreen_image, container, false);
        mImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (FullScreenActivity.class.isInstance(getActivity())) {
            final int resId = ItemList.LISTA_GALLERY_ID[mImageNum];
            // Call out to ImageDetailActivity to load the bitmap in a background thread
            ((FullScreenActivity) getActivity()).loadBitmap(resId, mImageView);
        }
    }
}
```

}

the logcat

```
      02-08 19:30:46.680: D/libEGL(12466): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
02-08 19:30:46.684: D/libEGL(12466): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
02-08 19:30:46.727: D/OpenGLRenderer(12466): Enabling debug mode 0
02-08 19:30:47.625: I/Choreographer(12466): Skipped 613 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-08 19:30:50.336: I/Choreographer(12466): Skipped 68 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-08 19:30:50.934: I/Choreographer(12466): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-08 19:31:02.789: D/dalvikvm(12466): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
02-08 19:31:02.899: D/dalvikvm(12466): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
02-08 19:31:06.043: I/Choreographer(12466): Skipped 186 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-08 19:31:06.109: D/dalvikvm(12466): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
02-08 19:31:06.289: D/dalvikvm(12466): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
02-08 19:31:11.266: D/dalvikvm(12466): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
02-08 19:31:11.367: D/dalvikvm(12466): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
02-08 19:31:11.488: D/dalvikvm(12466): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
02-08 19:31:11.590: D/dalvikvm(12466): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
02-08 19:31:11.711: D/dalvikvm(12466): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
02-08 19:31:11.762: D/dalvikvm(12466): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
02-08 19:31:19.406: I/Choreographer(12466): Skipped 456 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-08 19:31:20.043: I/dalvikvm-heap(12466): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 6297616-byte allocation
02-08 19:31:20.074: E/dalvikvm-heap(12466): Out of memory on a 6297616-byte allocation.
02-08 19:31:20.074: I/dalvikvm(12466): "AsyncTask #5" prio=5 tid=16 RUNNABLE
02-08 19:31:20.074: I/dalvikvm(12466):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x42400f38 self=0x4e3b0bb8
02-08 19:31:20.074: I/dalvikvm(12466):   | sysTid=12523 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1313770208
02-08 19:31:20.074: I/dalvikvm(12466):   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=63 stm=3 core=0
02-08 19:31:20.074: I/dalvikvm(12466):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
02-08 19:31:20.082: I/dalvikvm(12466):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:503)
02-08 19:31:20.082: I/dalvikvm(12466):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:356)
02-08 19:31:20.086: I/dalvikvm(12466):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:379)
02-08 19:31:20.086: I/dalvikvm(12466):   at com.example.parrucchieriprova.helper.Utils.decodeBitmapFromResource(Utils.java:26)
02-08 19:31:20.086: I/dalvikvm(12466):   at com.example.parrucchieriprova.FullScreenActivity$BitmapWorkerTask.doInBackground(FullScreenActivity.java:63)
02-08 19:31:20.086: I/dalvikvm(12466):   at com.example.parrucchieriprova.FullScreenActivity$BitmapWorkerTask.doInBackground(FullScreenActivity.java:1)
02-08 19:31:20.094: I/dalvikvm(12466):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-08 19:31:20.106: I/dalvikvm(12466):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-08 19:31:20.106: I/dalvikvm(12466):   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-08 19:31:20.106: I/dalvikvm(12466):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-08 19:31:20.106: I/dalvikvm(12466):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-08 19:31:20.109: I/dalvikvm(12466):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-08 19:31:20.109: D/skia(12466): --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
02-08 19:31:20.195: D/dalvikvm(12466): threadid=16: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
02-08 19:31:23.082: D/dalvikvm(12466): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
02-08 19:31:23.082: W/dalvikvm(12466): threadid=16: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418d47c0)
02-08 19:31:23.117: E/AndroidRuntime(12466): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
02-08 19:31:23.117: E/AndroidRuntime(12466): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-08 19:31:23.117: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
02-08 19:31:23.117: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
02-08 19:31:23.117: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
02-08 19:31:23.117: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
02-08 19:31:23.117: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-08 19:31:23.117: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-08 19:31:23.117: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-08 19:31:23.117: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-08 19:31:23.117: E/AndroidRuntime(12466): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
02-08 19:31:23.117: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
02-08 19:31:23.117: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:503)
02-08 19:31:23.117: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:356)
02-08 19:31:23.117: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:379)
02-08 19:31:23.117: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at com.example.parrucchieriprova.helper.Utils.decodeBitmapFromResource(Utils.java:26)
02-08 19:31:23.117: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at com.example.parrucchieriprova.FullScreenActivity$BitmapWorkerTask.doInBackground(FullScreenActivity.java:63)
02-08 19:31:23.117: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at com.example.parrucchieriprova.FullScreenActivity$BitmapWorkerTask.doInBackground(FullScreenActivity.java:1)
02-08 19:31:23.117: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-08 19:31:23.117: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-08 19:31:23.117: E/AndroidRuntime(12466):    ... 4 more
02-08 19:31:26.383: I/Process(12466): Sending signal. PID: 12466 SIG: 9
02-08 19:31:27.442: D/libEGL(12526): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
02-08 19:31:27.461: D/libEGL(12526): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
02-08 19:31:27.469: D/libEGL(12526): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
02-08 19:31:27.512: D/OpenGLRenderer(12526): Enabling debug mode 0
02-08 19:31:28.672: I/Choreographer(12526): Skipped 99 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-08 19:31:46.328: I/dalvikvm-heap(12526): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 15369616-byte allocation
02-08 19:31:46.356: E/dalvikvm-heap(12526): Out of memory on a 15369616-byte allocation.
02-08 19:31:46.356: I/dalvikvm(12526): "AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=12 RUNNABLE
02-08 19:31:46.356: I/dalvikvm(12526):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x423a9840 self=0x4e6bb9e8
02-08 19:31:46.356: I/dalvikvm(12526):   | sysTid=12540 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1234453912
02-08 19:31:46.356: I/dalvikvm(12526):   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=35 stm=1 core=0
02-08 19:31:46.356: I/dalvikvm(12526):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
02-08 19:31:46.359: I/dalvikvm(12526):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:503)
02-08 19:31:46.359: I/dalvikvm(12526):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:356)
02-08 19:31:46.359: I/dalvikvm(12526):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:379)
02-08 19:31:46.359: I/dalvikvm(12526):   at com.example.parrucchieriprova.helper.Utils.decodeBitmapFromResource(Utils.java:26)
02-08 19:31:46.359: I/dalvikvm(12526):   at com.example.parrucchieriprova.FullScreenActivity$BitmapWorkerTask.doInBackground(FullScreenActivity.java:63)
02-08 19:31:46.359: I/dalvikvm(12526):   at com.example.parrucchieriprova.FullScreenActivity$BitmapWorkerTask.doInBackground(FullScreenActivity.java:1)
02-08 19:31:46.359: I/dalvikvm(12526):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-08 19:31:46.359: I/dalvikvm(12526):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-08 19:31:46.359: I/dalvikvm(12526):   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-08 19:31:46.359: I/dalvikvm(12526):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-08 19:31:46.359: I/dalvikvm(12526):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-08 19:31:46.359: I/dalvikvm(12526):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-08 19:31:46.363: D/skia(12526): --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
02-08 19:31:46.363: W/dalvikvm(12526): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418d47c0)
02-08 19:31:46.371: E/AndroidRuntime(12526): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
02-08 19:31:46.371: E/AndroidRuntime(12526): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-08 19:31:46.371: E/AndroidRuntime(12526):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
02-08 19:31:46.371: E/AndroidRuntime(12526):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
02-08 19:31:46.371: E/AndroidRuntime(12526):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
02-08 19:31:46.371: E/AndroidRuntime(12526):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
02-08 19:31:46.371: E/AndroidRuntime(12526):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-08 19:31:46.371: E/AndroidRuntime(12526):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-08 19:31:46.371: E/AndroidRuntime(12526):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-08 19:31:46.371: E/AndroidRuntime(12526):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-08 19:31:46.371: E/AndroidRuntime(12526): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
02-08 19:31:46.371: E/AndroidRuntime(12526):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
02-08 19:31:46.371: E/AndroidRuntime(12526):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:503)
02-08 19:31:46.371: E/AndroidRuntime(12526):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:356)
02-08 19:31:46.371: E/AndroidRuntime(12526):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:379)
02-08 19:31:46.371: E/AndroidRuntime(12526):    at com.example.parrucchieriprova.helper.Utils.decodeBitmapFromResource(Utils.java:26)
02-08 19:31:46.371: E/AndroidRuntime(12526):    at com.example.parrucchieriprova.FullScreenActivity$BitmapWorkerTask.doInBackground(FullScreenActivity.java:63)
02-08 19:31:46.371: E/AndroidRuntime(12526):    at com.example.parrucchieriprova.FullScreenActivity$BitmapWorkerTask.doInBackground(FullScreenActivity.java:1)
02-08 19:31:46.371: E/AndroidRuntime(12526):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-08 19:31:46.371: E/AndroidRuntime(12526):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-08 19:31:46.371: E/AndroidRuntime(12526):    ... 4 more
02-08 19:31:55.117: I/Process(12526): Sending signal. PID: 12526 SIG: 9
02-08 19:32:07.188: D/libEGL(12554): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
02-08 19:32:07.195: D/libEGL(12554): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
02-08 19:32:07.203: D/libEGL(12554): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
02-08 19:32:07.246: D/OpenGLRenderer(12554): Enabling debug mode 0
02-08 19:32:08.067: I/Choreographer(12554): Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-08 19:32:27.145: I/Choreographer(12554): Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-08 19:33:08.199: I/Choreographer(12554): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-08 19:33:43.828: I/Choreographer(12554): Skipped 57 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-08 19:34:39.531: I/Choreographer(12554): Skipped 64 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-08 19:35:06.149: I/Choreographer(12554): Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-08 19:35:08.539: I/Choreographer(12554): Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-08 19:35:12.774: I/Choreographer(12554): Skipped 47 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: Why are you using FragmentStatePagerAdapter? When you are dealing with images, saving big bitmaps as part of fragments backed by FragmentStatePagerAdapter will make all of them stay in memory as long as Activity is not destroyed. Try using FragmentPagerAdapter only.

Comment: Because of this "This version of the pager is more useful when there are a large number of pages, working more like a list view. When pages are not visible to the user, their entire fragment may be destroyed, only keeping the saved state of that fragment. This allows the pager to hold on to much less memory associated with each visited page as compared to FragmentPagerAdapter at the cost of potentially more overhead when switching between pages".

Comment: But You have only limited number of memory to play with. You can't put so many large bitmaps (8 of them) in RAM all the time as it is bound to cause OutOfMemory error.

Comment: I scale every bitmap ( with in sample size) to adapt the actual screen of the device but how can I put a single bitmap per time in ram?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to consume to much much memory.

Bitmap of size 2560*1600 will need 2560*1600*4 = over 15MB memory.
So if you are trying to allocate many of them you are running out of memory.

Using `inSampleSize` loads your bitmap smaller (so it need less memory).

Comment: I already use it, according to Google doc, but the problem, i think, is that All pages of pageadapter are keep in memory

Comment: If you think that bitmaps are remaining in memory try to `recycle()` them when fragment is beeing destroyed. [Read this link](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) (or any other ImageLoading library) to load your bitmaps. Reason being, as you can see first hand, there are multiple ways to do it incorrectly and/or run out of memory. All these ImageLoading/Caching libraries follow the best practices with ease of use.

There are so many ways to screw image loading in Android, that I always insist on using a well known library to do it for you. The Google's response, Volley, is nice, but does a lot of stuff and it requires a lot more work to "just load an image".

There are more out there, check 'em out (Android Universal Image Loader, android-query, etc). Picasso is the simplest one (in my opinion). Drop the .jar, call `Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(imageview);` (that's the simplest form).

Comment: I am using Picasso for loading images in ViewPager, still getting OOM issue. Can you please help me.

Comment: And how do you expect me to help you? :)